# Configuring env-entry values in WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

In WAS Full Profile you can change the values for env-entries defined in an application's web.xml file while and after deployment. Is there any such feature in WebSphere Liberty profile?

Sample env-entry:

```
<env-entry>
    <description>Some Config String</description>
    <env-entry-name>MyConfigString</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>Dev-Value to be replaced in Production during deployment</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

This env-entry is injected with an @Resource(name = "MyConfigString") annotation.

The [infocenter for IBM Worklight](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html) (which runs on Liberty) describes a way using jndiEntry elements in server.xml . I tried this on Liberty 8.5.5.3 but it does not work and still injects the default value from web.xml.

Has anybody found a working way to configure env-entry values in Liberty?

Answer (score 1):

The Liberty profile doesn't currently support configuring bindings without modifying the ibm-*-bnd.xml files in the application. As a workaround, you can use:

```
@Resource(lookup="MyConfigString")
```

...in the application and:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="MyConfigString" value='"xyz"'/>
```

...in server.xml as described in the [knowledge center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jndi.html).